# bootstrap toggler not showing content

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

help me with this , the toggler icon is not showing any content.
I used bootstrap 5.1 in the code. The toggler icon in the navbar does not show any content when clicked

'''

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>TinDog</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
 <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
 rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384- 
 1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>


 <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark" >
   <div class="container-fluid">
     <a class="navbar-brand "href="">tindog</a>
     <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs- 
    target="#navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-expanded="false" 
    aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
     <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
       <li class="nav-item">
         <a class="nav-link"href="#">Contact</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link"href="#">Pricing</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link"href="#">Download</a>
      </li>
    </ul>


  </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

'''

Comment: Do you need to load also BS javascript library maybe? How does the toggle work.

Answer (score 0):

This basic navbar could help you as a start.

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" 
crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            Dropdown
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="d-flex">
        <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: read more here : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/navbar/

Comment: I followed the exact information in the above link and ended up the same.

Comment: @Jtmuthu ok, well the above (my answer) code works; try to copy and paste the code in my answer, and customize it to your needs? You could work directly from this Pen for example https://codepen.io/thewhitegrizzli/pen/ZEJeOzv